# How to display a date by using c:out tag in some format

Tags: jsp, jstl

I am using JSTL. I want to display a date in JSP using `<c:out ..>` tag.

I tried `<c:out value = "<fmt:formatdate value = '${datevar}'"/>`.

But it displays as `<fmt:formatdate value = '${datevar}'` in the HTML.

What needs to be changed to display date with expected format?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You don't need `<c:out>` and the tag is actually called `<fmt:formatDate>` (note the uppercase `D`).

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${datevar}" pattern="MM/yyyy" />
```

If you actually want to store it in some variable to redisplay later in `<c:out>`, then use `var` attribute.

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${datevar}" pattern="MM/yyyy" var="newdatevar" />
...
<c:out value="${newdatevar}" />
```

Comment: Then specify that in the `pattern` attribute. I updated the answer. See also documentation: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatDate.html Note that `YYYY` is an invalid pattern for years, it should be `yyyy`. See also http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html